# Enumerable.Any() is very Slow on Large Linq Data Set

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm running code like this:

```
var somethings = db.Somethings.Select(s => new SomethingViewModel
{
    Id = s.Id,
    Name = s.Name,
    IsActive = s.IsActive
    SubSomethings = s.SubSomethings.Select(ss => new SubSomethingViewModel
    {
        Id = ss.Id,
        Name = ss.Name,
        IsActive = ss.IsActive
    }).Where(wss => wss.IsActive)                        
}).Where(ws => ws.IsActive && (ws.SubSomethings.Any())) //remove elements if no SubSomethings
.ToList();
```

As you can see, this is a one to many relationship. There are a list of SubSomethings in a Something. If I take out the  && (ws.SubSomethings.Any()), I get a very fast list returned.

But, I want to only include in the list the Somethings that have at least one SubSomething. I also tried the following and got the same horrible efficiency:

```
var somethings = db.Somethings.Select(s => new SomethingViewModel
{
    Id = s.Id,
    Name = s.Name,
    IsActive = s.IsActive
    SubSomethings = s.SubSomethings.Select(ss => new SubSomethingViewModel
    {
        Id = ss.Id,
        Name = ss.Name,
        IsActive = ss.IsActive
    }).Where(wss => wss.IsActive)                        
}).Where(ws => ws.IsActive)
.ToList(); //this finishes very quickly

var somethings2 = somethings.Where(s => s.SubSomethings.Any()).ToList(); //This is where the code bogged down
```

How can I re-write my query to get the bogging down code to be much faster? One thing to note: This works just fine with one or two records. When I hit >8000 records, it takes at least four minutes.

Here is the Index I created on the SubSomething table for the foreign Key of SomethingId, which corresponds to Something.Id

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SubSomething_SomethingId] ON [dbo].[SubSomething]
(
    [SomethingId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Here is the foreign key creation of SubSomething.SomethingId:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SubSomething]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SubSomething_Something_SomethingId] FOREIGN KEY([SomethingId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Something] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SubSomething] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SubSomething_Something_SomethingId]
GO
```

Comment: It should give you the same result, but to try will not hurt, what happens if instead of `ws.SubSomethings.Any()` you use `ws.SubSomethings.Count() > 0`?

Comment: @Gusman - that will be slower as Count needs to consume the entire data

Comment: @Gusman - if anything, the `Count()` approach would be slower, as it needs to iterate over all items in order to get the count (there are some shortcuts for specific collection types, but not all of them). `Any()` just needs one element.

Comment: Yes. .Count > 0 was tried with the same result.

Comment: What does the query that is sent to the server look like?  Do a .ToString() instead of a .ToList() on your first version to get it. Also what does the query plan look like for it if you run it inside SSMS?

Comment: @GiladGreen nope, it will translate to a SQL Count which will use the length of the primary key index.

Comment: You probably should fetch the data in two queries.

Comment: @Gusman It can't translate to SQL, at least not in the OP's second form. The `.Any()` is in an expression using only `Enumerable`'s methods, there's nothing left there that `Queryable` could act on.

Comment: @Gert Arnold: Can you show me what that would look like?

Comment: Have you created index on foreign keys?

Comment: Yes. I will post the index in the OP.

Comment: @hvd yes, on the second case it's true, I was talking about the first one, my bad to not specify it.

Comment: The comment in your second attempt `//This is where the code bogged down` sounds very suspicious - smells like EF Core. What EF version are you using?

Comment: EF Core. Version 1.1.##

Comment: Boom! This is what you should started with! (all other tags including `enumerable` doesn't matter). I think you are simply out of luck - whatever you do, it will execute 8000+ subqueries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EF Core is your problem. Currently it's known to execute N + 1 subqueries when the query contains sub collection projection.

The only way to workaround it and limit the whole thing to 2 SQL queries is to filter as much as you can, then load the whole entity set with sub entities in memory using eager loading, then switch to LINQ to Objects and do the final projection/filtering:

```
var somethings = db.Somethings
    .Include(s => s.SubSomethings)
    .Where(s => s.IsActive)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(s => new SomethingViewModel
    {
        Id = s.Id,
        Name = s.Name,
        IsActive = s.IsActive,
        SubSomethings = s.SubSomethings.Select(ss => new SubSomethingViewModel
        {
            Id = ss.Id,
            Name = ss.Name,
            IsActive = ss.IsActive
        }).Where(wss => wss.IsActive).ToList()
    })
    .Where(s => s.SubSomethings.Any())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are casting the first query to a list. Try this instead:

```
var products = db.Products.Where(ws => ws.IsActive && ws.SubSomethings.Count(ss => ss.IsActive) > 0)
.Select(p => new SomethingViewModel
{
    Id = p.Id,
    Name = p.Name,
    IsActive = p.IsActive,
    SubSomethings = p.SubSomethings.Select(ss => new PartViewModel
    {
        Id = ss.Id,
        Name = ss.Name,
        IsActive = ss.IsActive
    }).Where(wss => wss.IsActive)   
}).ToList();
```

Comment: This just replaces the OP's second attempt by the OP's first attempt, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah. I can't see any difference.

Comment: Yes. I was giving this a second thought and I think you need to NOT project the fields until you return the results. I am working on a fix.

Comment: There. That should cause all the joins and filtering to occur on the server side.

Comment: This actually works very very well. And it does highlight that I was doing things a bit backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `SubSomethings` property of each `Something` is remaining an enumerable whose underlying database query isn't executed until your last line of code. So in that line, you're sequentially executing 1 database query for each Something.

I would suggest an Include() of SubSomethings in your initial query so that all your data is fetched together via an inner join:

```
var somethings = db.Somethings
    .Include("SubSomethings") // added this
    .Select(s => new SomethingViewModel
{
    Id = s.Id,
    Name = s.Name,
    IsActive = s.IsActive
    SubSomethings = s.SubSomethings.Select(ss => new SubSomethingViewModel
    {
        Id = ss.Id,
        Name = ss.Name,
        IsActive = ss.IsActive
    }).Where(wss => wss.IsActive)                        
}).Where(ws => ws.IsActive)
.ToList(); //this finishes very quickly

var somethings2 = somethings.Where(s => s.SubSomethings.Any()).ToList(); //This is where the code bogged down
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Code added. If that doesn't do the trick, you could try additionally doing a ToList() at the time of assigning to the SubSomethings property.

Answer (score 0):

As Ivan Stoev said, EF Core is your problem, i share a alternative not using LINQ to SQL but that ill mutch better performance:

1. Create a View in database with the logic to join the data that you need
2. Use db.Database.SqlQuery("Query") to query the view and return the data:

   var results = db.Database.SqlQuery< SomethingViewModel >("Select ColA,ColB,ColC from ViewSomething")

   The object SomethingViewModel must be a strongly type with propreties matching to cols of the view.

I know that is not pretty and have the hardcoded query for the view, but Generally is the fastest performance you get using EF since you pass compiler.